# django-filter using filter class in another filter class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I have two models named Person and Member. In the member, the person is defined as a foreign key. Here as an example I added less fields, normally PersonModel has much more fields. What I want to do here is to use all the filter fields I created for the person in the filter class I created for Member. For this, I created PersonWidet with a field named PersonField. The filter works very well, but the labels of the inputs are not visible in the DRF view

[image: DRF Form Page]

enums.py

```
class GenderTypeEnum:
    FEMALE = 1
    MALE = 2
    UNKNOWN = 3

    types = (
        (FEMALE, _("Female")),
        (MALE, _("Male")),
        (UNKNOWN, _("Unknown"))
    )
```

models.py

```
class PersonModel(models.Model):
  identity=models.CharField(unique=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  gender = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    choices=GenderTypeEnum.types,
    default=GenderTypeEnum.UNKNOWN
)

class MemberModel(models.Model)
  register_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  person = filters.ForeignKey(PersonModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='members')
```

widgets.py

```
class PersonWidget(SuffixedMultiWidget):
    template_name = "django_filters/widgets/multiwidget.html"
    suffixes = ["identity", "name", "last_name", "gender"]

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        print("p"*100, attrs)
        widgets = (
            forms.TextInput,
            forms.TextInput,
            forms.TextInput,
            forms.Select
        )
        super().__init__(widgets, attrs)
```

fields.py

```
class PersonField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = PersonWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        fields = [
            forms.CharField(label=_('Identity')),
            forms.CharField(label=_('Name')),
            forms.CharField(label=_('Last Name')),
            forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Gender"), choices=GenderTypeEnum.types,
                              widget=forms.Select),
        ]

        super().__init__(fields=fields, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
            return {
                'identity': data_list[0],
                'name': data_list[1],
                'last_name': data_list[2],
                'gender': data_list[3]
            }
        return None
```

filters.py

```
class PersonFilter(Filter):
    field_class = PersonField

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.relation = kwargs.pop('relation', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            filter = {}
            identity = value.get('identity', None)
            if identity:
                field = self.get_field("identity__icontains")
                filter.update({field: identity})

            name = value.get('name', None)
            if name:
                field = self.get_field("name__icontains")
                filter.update({field: name})

            last_name = value.get('last_name', None)
            if last_name:
                field = self.get_field("last_name__icontains")
                filter.update({field: last_name})

            gender = value.get('gender', None)
            if gender:
                field = self.get_field("gender")
                filter.update({field: gender})

            if filter:
                return qs.filter(**filter)

        return super().filter(qs, None)

    def get_field(self, field):
        f = ""
        if self.relation:
            f = f"{self.relation}__{field}"
        else:
            f = field

        return f
```

filter_sets.py

```
class MemberFilter(filters.FilterSet):
  
   person = PersonFilter(relation="person")
   register_no = filters.CharFilter(field_name='register_no')
```